# Stop Autoplaying Youtube video in the background when it is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I have a popup on my website which has a YouTube video in the iframe set to auto-play.
The problem is it plays in the background, even if the popup is not visible. All I am trying to do is to get the `display` status of the popup container if it is hidden or not.

Like the following.

```
function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("popupVid");
    if(div.style.display == 'hide')
    {
        $('#iframe_id').remove();
    }
}
```

So based on this status, can I remove the iframe? or any other option to avoid youtube being played in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the iframe, you could load the video via the youtube API, and call the pause function. This would allow the user to close the pop-up and resume the video.

player.pauseVideo():Void

Pauses the currently playing video. The final player state after this function executes will be paused (2) unless the player is in the ended (0) state when the function is called, in which case the player state will not change.

documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

Comment: Can I write `popupafterclose: function () {               $("#popupVideo").html("<span></span>"); }`